# How to assign strings a number value within Java

Tags: java

So I am doing this project on Rock Paper Scissors, something with 5,059 combinations, but that's besides the point. 
In my case, being a beginner, I was wondering if it is possible to make each option a string and then later convert those strings to integers. 
Or as Candied Orange was saying, would a Hash Map be more efficient?

Comment: Why do they need a number value?

Comment: I'm doing a massive Rock Paper Scissors project

Comment: But what are the strings? What do the numbers represent and how will you use them?

Comment: In theory, I was gonna have them type the string in with a scanner and then depending on what they type in, convert that string to a int. I'm not sure how else I'd do it, im a beginner in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums can do this well, as can a hash map.  Depends when you want to create the relationship.  Choose enumes for design time.  Hash for run time.

Yes, implementing a hash table is possible in Java.  You can also just use the one already implemented in `java.util` called `HashTable`.  But unless you're doing funky multi threaded stuff I recommend `HashMap`, from the same package, which is the same except not synchronized and so is a bit faster.

Keep in mind that  programmers is not a code writing service but I was bored so I'm going to drive home my point with 60 lines that use both ideas in a glorious fit of over engineering.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class StringsToNumbers {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<Converter> converters = Arrays.asList(new MapConverter(),new EnumConverter());
        List<String> numerals = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");

        for (Converter con : converters) {
            for (String num : numerals) {
                System.out.print(con.convert(num));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

```
interface Converter {
    int convert(String str);
}

// Assigned at run time
class MapConverter implements Converter {
    public int convert(String str){
        Map<String, Integer> s2i = new HashMap<>();
        s2i.put("One",1);
        s2i.put("Two",2);
        s2i.put("Three",3);

        return s2i.get(str);
    }
}

// Assigned at design time
enum StrToNum {
    One(1), Two(2), Three(3);

    int value;
    StrToNum(int v) {
        value = v;
    }
    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class EnumConverter implements Converter {
    public int convert(String str) {
        return StrToNum.valueOf(str).getValue();
    }
}
```

Displays

```
123
123
```

Note how `MapConverter.convert()` completely inefficiently rebuilds the `HashMap` each time it's called.  This is just to show that unlike Enum the map can be changed at run time.  A HashMap could be used in the design time case as well if we built it at construction time.

Comment: How would you implement a hash table? I did some research, and would it be possible in Java?

Comment: It's certainly possible, considering that the standard library actually did it (`java.util.HashMap`).

Comment: @ChaseHughes Here's a little example of use.  I leave reading user input as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: @dan04 is that what I import?

Comment: @ChaseHughes yes `java.util.HashMap` is what you should import if you don't want to use enums.  You should see it twice in the answer.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I just saw your more in depth answer, for some reason it was not loading completely and I was only seeing the first three sentences!

Comment: @ChaseHughes yeah, don't trust the back button here without following it with a readload.